# AEM Query Builder property value is not empty

Tags: aem, query-builder

How can I get results in the query builder snippet below that the **industries** page property has a value? (i.e., its value is *not* an empty string)

```
path=/content/apps
type=nt:unstructured
property=industries
property.value=
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `like` operation for using the [jcr:like xpath function][1]

```
path=/content/apps
type=nt:unstructured
property=industries
property.value=%_%
property.operation=like
```

The corresponding xpath query would be

```
/jcr:root/content/apps//element(*, nt:unstructured)
[
(jcr:like(@industries, '%_%')) 
]
```

Quoting the docs

> As in SQL, the character ‘%’ represents any string of zero or more characters, and the character ‘_’ (underscore) represents any single character.

Please note that if the value contains a space alone, it is still considered valid as this function doesn't trim and then validate. Only if there is no value then it is excluded from the results.